# Predictor coef in mixed effects model equation

Tags: r, mixed-model

This model `lmer (y ~ x + (1 + x | county))` can be written like that
[image]

$a_j$ & $\beta_j$ show that the slope and the intercept is different (varying) per county $j$.

$\mu_a$ & $\mu_\beta$ are the mean of intercept and slop. Nice.

But where is the fixed effect coefficient for $x_i$ in this equation? Is it the $\mu_\beta$?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", $\mu_\alpha$ and $\mu_\beta$ are the fixed-effect coefficients. Note that $\mu_\beta$ is the expected value, which is estimated by the fit, and not the sample mean.

Comment: Indeed, you have to view the alpha_j and beta_j as county-specific deviations from the fixed intercept and slope. So the expectations of those deviations equal the fixed intercept and slope.